# visualize tuple with entities grouped

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a tuple with named entity values in a Dataframe, how do I group the values by each entities over the column containing tuples and visualize it.

```
s = pd.Series("At noon, Trump became the 45th president of the United States, taking the oath of office with Chief Justice John Roberts. Trump was also sworn in using two Bibles, a Bible his mother gifted him and the historic Lincoln Bible.")

print(hero.named_entities(s)[0])
```

which outputs

```
[('noon', 'TIME', 3, 7), ('Trump', 'PERSON', 9, 14), ('45th', 'ORDINAL', 26, 30), ('the United States', 'GPE', 44, 61), ('John Roberts', 'PERSON', 108, 120), ('two', 'CARDINAL', 152, 155), ('Bibles', 'PRODUCT', 156, 162), ('Bible', 'WORK_OF_ART', 166, 171), ('Lincoln Bible', 'PERSON', 211, 224)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "a tuple with named entity values in a Dataframe". You have "a list of tuples".
In order to do that, you have to follow the instructions below:

Use a for-loop to iterate through a list of tuples. Within the for-loop, use the indexing syntax tuple[0] to access the first element of each tuple, and call list.append(object) with object as the tuple's first element to append each first element to list.

As shown [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-the-first-element-of-each-tuple-in-a-list-in-python#:%7E:text=Use%20indexing%20to%20get%20the,each%20first%20element%20to%20list%20.)

And then, if you want you can transform each list to DataFrame using pandas.

Also for anyone else who wants to run this command:
`print(hero.named_entities(s)[0])`

Υou have to import the following package:
`import texthero as hero`

Comment: the series is already inside a column value inside the Dataframe, how should I proceed?

Comment: this is your list of tuples:
lst_of_tuples = hero.named_entities(s)[0] 
Use this list and follow the instructions on my reference! It's better if you do your test on a console, so you can see the variables you are creating at the same time. (I use Pycharm console for that)